# Programatically change price to Ubercart item when added to cart

Tags: drupal, ubercart, cart

I have built a Javascript app that provides custom configuration for a product. From that JS app I submit the relevant data to a Drupal module which I've also prepared. The purpose of the module is to validate input and submit the details to the Ubercart system.

I need to submit a custom price based on the items chosen from that module when the custom build is submitted from the module. I have looked at uc_variable_price, uc_custom_price and the hook_add_to_cart but I'm not seeing a way to add the custom price programmatically.

Comment: check the logic in uc_custom_price, add your custom logic there. I did the same for one of my project and everything works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_cart_item().
 */
function module_cart_item($op, &$item) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'load':
      $order = db_result(
        db_query("SELECT price_total FROM {module_orders} WHERE id = %d", 
          $id)
        );
      if (!empty($order)) {
        $item->price = $order;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Check the logic

Comment: You should at least add a few more words to describe your answer.